# Visual Studio 2015 Preview install error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I am trying to install the new preview for Visual studio 2015, every time I run the installer I get the error:

This version of Visual Studio requires the April 2014 update to Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 known as KB 2919355.

I have run the windows updater, so don't know what the problem is.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When I've tried to install [KB 2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355) - I got next message:

> this update is not applicable to your windows...

Than from '''Known issues with this update''' section I've installed next updates:

- [2939087](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2939087)
- [2975061](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2975061)

Rebooted system and installed 2919355 update again.

Answer (score 1):

This was my major problem after a fresh install of Windows 8.1 Pro. When i was trying to install Visual Studio Community it required the KB 2919355 and i was more careful and downloaded the specific update for x64 system architecture.. and it worked for me  !